# How to get a not equal in a while loop in GMP

Tags: c++, gmp

I'm Trying to do a do-while loop in VC 2008 Express using GMP integers

```
mpz_t d;    
mpz_init(d);
do{


}while(d!=1);
```

The Error is: error C2040: '!=' : 'mpz_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
The d!=1 part is causing this. What ways around this. The reason im using GMP is for big numbers.

Comment: Even for s.o. with more specific knowdlege of GMP, this question seriously lacks enough information to diagnose your problem!

Comment: Check if my answer solves your problem (I'm aware of what your purpose using GMP is). What you're asking is completely different now! Stick to `mpz_cmp()` comparing the _big numbers_!

Comment: Please **add** additional info with your question, without completely replace the original code! That invalidated my original answer, which isn't very nice ...

Comment: mpz_t is not integer. Use mpz functions to compare mpz values.

Comment: Look up `mpz_class` (in `gmpxx.h`).

Answer (score 3):

As from the [docs](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/gmp_4.html)

> Function: `int mpz_cmp (MP_INT *operand1, MP_INT *operand2)`
>   ...
>   Compare `operand1` and `operand2`. Return a positive value if `operand1 > operand2`, **zero** if
>   `operand1 == operand2`, and a negative value if `operand1 < operand2`.

Check the `mpz_set_<xx>` functions to setup a `mpz_t` value from a regular integer constant (as `1` represents) to compare with

```
mpz_t d;    
mpz_init(&d);
mpz_t one;
mpz_set_si(&one,1);

// ...
do {
} while(mpz_cmp(&d,&one) != 0);
```